# DBLookupComboBox - How to clear the selected item?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

What I tried to achieve is like setting ItemIndex to -1 as like in normal ComboBox, so that the selected item will be cleared.

There is no ItemIndex for DBLookupComboBox, and the Text property is read only. So how do I clear the selected item? Please help. Many thanks in advance.

PS: Closing and reopening the DBLookupComboBox->ListSource DataSet does not help.

Comment: I solved the problem with DBLookupComboBox->KeyValue = ""; since the data type in the ListFields are of type String. Thanks to Kutsoff and John Easley for giving me a clue to the solutions. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways:

1)  at runtime: DbLookupComboBox.KeyValue := null;

2)  at design-time: set the DbLookupComboBox.NullValueKey property to DEL (or whatever key you want to use to null the value during runtime)

Comment: 1) Throws EVariantTypeCastError.
2) Causes an Access Violation.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: 1) usually happens when the lookup key and keyfields mismatch.  If your keyfield is a string, then yes, you can assign ''.  2) I've never experienced this..sorry..

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
DBLookupComboBox.KeyValue := -1;
```

Comment: Setting KeyValue does reset the selected item, but throws EVariantTypeCastError exception. I'm using C++Builder 2009, not sure if this has anythong to do with the exception. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

DBLookupComboBox represents the value of a field of a database. So you have to clear/change the value of the field to clear/change the value of the DBLookupComboBox by code.

Answer (score 0):

if first time you set dblokupcombobox KeyField in property is 'city' //example

if you want to clear selected item you can use this

```
procedure TFtreset.BitBtn6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dblookupcombobox2.KeyValue:='city';
end;
```