# Setting TDBLookupComboBox to blank in c++

Tags: combobox, c++builder

I am using a TDBLookupComboBox in Embarcadero C++ Builder to list some fields from a DataBase, but I need to have the option of setting the selected value "TDBLookupComboBox ->Text" to be empty. I need this because I have other components connected to the ComboBox and I will need to be able to send either the value pulled from the DataBase OR nothing.

I looked at the win32 API SendMessage function, but as TDBLookupComboBox doesn't inherit from ComboBox, I am out of luck. Does anybody have an implementation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to this.

Found it elsewhere when searching for slightly different things.

I am wondering if you can only have one NullValueKey however.  That seems odd.

[DBLookupComboBox - How to clear the selected item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740897/dblookupcombobox-how-to-clear-the-selected-item)